# Caclulate $\iiint \operatorname{div} \vec{F} \mathrm{~d} V $ in cylindrical coordinates, $\vec{F}$ is a vector field

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

The vector field $\vec{F}$ is originally given in Cartesian coordinates.

Hello, my question is whether I can first determine the divergence in Cartesian coordinates and then switch to cylindrical coordinates(Option A)? Or first describe the vectorfield in cylindrical coordinates and then use the divergence operator for cylindrical coordinates(Option B)?
Which way is better?

Option a)

$$\iiint \operatorname{div} \vec{F} \mathrm{~d} V=\iiint \frac{\partial\bar{F}_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\vec{F}_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial\bar{F}_z}{\partial z} \mathrm{~d} V=\iiint \Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{\partial\bar{F}_x}{\partial x}\Bigr)(r,\phi,z)+\Bigl(\frac{\partial\vec{F}_y}{\partial y}\Bigr)(r,\phi,z)+\Bigl(\frac{\partial\bar{F}_z}{\partial z}\Bigr)(r,\phi,z)\Bigr] r \mathrm{d} r \mathrm{d} \varphi \mathrm{d} z   $$

Option b)

$$\iiint \operatorname{div} \vec{F} \mathrm{~d} V=\iiint \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial(r\bar{F}_r)}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial(\vec{F}_\theta)}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial(\vec{F}_z)}{\partial z}
r \mathrm{d} r \mathrm{d} \varphi \mathrm{d} z $$

Comment: Do we agree: In both cases we will end with the same multiple integral?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is generally the case

Comment: Vector equations, as well as the operations of div, grad, and curl, are independent of the coordinate system we happen to use.